# WIX Bundle "This installation package could not be opened."

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Alright, so I've been working with the WIX installer and I'm working on building a bundle for bootstrapping the .NET framework. After a lot of reading the official material I've had issues with getting *any* bundle to start. I finally decided to strip it down to the minimum to try to figure out what's wrong. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="{0e0055fe-ce30-4b84-8b98-6a73128ff93d}"> 
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="NewPackage" SourceFile="C:\TestInstall.msi"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

It builds successfully, but when I run it I get the message "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

I'm guessing I'm missing some basic piece, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. What else do I need to add for the created MSI to run properly?

EDIT: Found the answer. Visual Studio 2012 doesn't compile Bundles properly with WIX 3.6.

Comment: As an addendum, since I'm new to wix myself and ran into a similar problem: I needed to create a bundle project of type `Bootstrapper Project` so that the Visual Studio plugin knows what to do.